# Multiple instances in Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-theory, instance

I'm really confuse with the term instance and database. So, my first question is how database and Instance are related in Oracle, I mean, whether an instance is associated with one/multiple database(s) or a database associated with single/multiple instance(s)?

And, my second question is, one of my friend says we can't have multiple instances in oracle. is it really valid a statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation explains it very well:

> An Oracle database server consists of an Oracle database and an Oracle
>   instance. Every time a database is started, a system global area (SGA)
>   is allocated and Oracle background processes are started. The
>   combination of the background processes and memory buffers is called
>   an Oracle instance.

An oracle database is the physical files that make up the database itself (control files, data files etc) - [Documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/intro.htm#sthref35).

A database is associated with one or more instances, with multiple instances making a RAC setup - [Documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/intro.htm#i60813). As far as your second question is concerned, multiple instances of a single database is a RAC setup.

Comment: can we have multiple instance running on same machine ?

Comment: @jWeavers yes, you can

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple instances on one machine that both mount the same database (a RAC configuaration), but this would be unusual. The multiuple instances of a RAC system would generally be on different machines except for special cases such as development or test systems.

You can have multiple non-RAC systems on a single machine, so of course each of those would have its own instance. This is common but not necessarily as efficient as combining the multiple databases into one.